# Is it possible to run Joomla in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, joomla, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to find a scalable way to run my Joomla installation with Amazon Web Services. I was very excited with the announcement of DynamoDB, but I'm not sure about the challenges to run Joomla on a NoSQL database.

Is it possible to run Joomla on a NoSQL database?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer "No" - not out of the box anyway.

Joomla has had support for developers to implement additional database support for a long time, it's just that there apparently hasn't been a big enough need

[Joomla 2.5 introduces additional databases](http://community.joomla.org/blogs/community/1533-new-features-in-joomla-25.html) (Postgress, Oracle, SQLite, PDO and Microsoft databases) and improves on the underlying mechanism to add support for other databases. So, in theory if you have the skills you could code the support for NoSQL.